# C# WPF Binding Path Data with Converter

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

i have a problem converting a string to a icon. The icon Geometry is in a ResourceDictionary. The ValueConverter is not called (i tried to debug in the Convert Method of the Converter). Here is my code:

xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:StatusToPathDataConverter x:Key="PathConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Path Width="20"
        Height="20"
        Stretch="Uniform"
        Fill="Black" 
        Data="{Binding Path=Status,
             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
             Converter={StaticResource PathConverter}}"/>
</Grid>
```

cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow :Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Status
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(StatusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StatusProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("Status", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow));


}
public class StatusToPathDataConverter :IValueConverter {
    private static ResourceDictionary iconDictionary;
    public ResourceDictionary IconDictionary
    {
        get
        {
            if(iconDictionary == null) {
                iconDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
                iconDictionary.Source = new Uri("/WPFBindingTest;component/Resources/IconDictionary.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            }
            return iconDictionary;
        }
    }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        var status = (string)value;
        if(statinStatus == null)
            return null;
        switch(status.ToLower()) {
            case "test":
                return IconDictionary["TestIcon"];
                // ...
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not binding to anything. You need to tell the `Binding` to go to the `Window` to find the `Status` property. The recommended way to do that is to use `RelativeSource`, as below:

```
<Path 
    Width="20"
    Height="20"
    Stretch="Uniform"
    Fill="Black" 
    Data="{Binding Path=Status,
         RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window},
         Converter={StaticResource PathConverter}}"
         />
```

As @Clemens notes, `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` doesn't make any sense on this binding and should not be there. That attribute tells the `Binding` when it should update the binding's source property. The source property is `Window.Status`, in this case.

However, the `Path.Data` property does not update the property it's bound to. A `Path` displays a `Geometry`; it doesn't edit a `Geometry`. `UpdateSourceTrigger` exists for control properties that update viewmodel properties, like `TextBox.Text`. That's the most common use for `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`: By default `TextBox.Text` updates the source property when the `TextBox` loses focus, but sometimes you want it to update on each keystroke.